# How do I best delete all references to a specific GUID from a SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database where records are identified by GUIDs, meaning all rows have a primary key of type `uniqueidentifier`.

Example:

```
Table A
-- Table B
-- Table C
```

So, a record in Table A has a given GUID as a PK, and records in Tables B and C have columns which are FKs to the record in Table A.  The records in Tables B and C cannot exist without the record in Table A.

Given a GUID *and with no knowledge of any tables in which it appears as a PK or an FK*, could I write a stored proc that simply vaporized everything related to that GUID?  I basically want to say:

> Hey SQL, I don't like this GUID anymore. Wipe it off the face of the Earth.

Here's my thinking:

- Find any column in any table that is a *nullable* FK containing that GUID, and set the column value to `NULL`
- Find any column in any table that is a *non-nullable* FK containing that GUID, and delete the row
- Find any column in any table that is a PK containing that GUID, and delete the row

(In theory, I could also find *any* column of *any* type in *any* table containing that GUID and set the value to `NULL`.  Since it's a GUID it can't really exist for any other reason than to (1) identify a row as a PK, or (2) reference that row as an FK.  But why would a GUID appear in a column unless it was a PK or an FK?)

Is my thinking correct, here?  I essentially want to purge all references to a logical object from a database.  That object is identified by a perfectly unique value, therefore I just need to go all "scorched earth" on that value.

I can't be the first person to want to do this. Do I need to roll my own stored proc for it, or I am unaware of some existing functionality here?

Comment: Well, you have the relationships setup through foreign keys, just turn on cascade delete

Comment: try removing the stuff related to guid/unique identifier - perhaps you can find a more general solution :)

Comment: @ganders The problem with cascading deletes is that it doesn't handle circular references.  It something is referenced from two tables, you can't cascade deletes down both "sides".